# PhpStorm + WordPress Project + "502 Bad Gateway error"

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

I have used WordPress on Cloud9 successfully previously, but I can't even get a new one to start via JetBrains IDE.

I have two machines: one Windows ([XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)) and one Mac ([MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP)) and getting the same "502 Bad Gateway" error when the browser tries to login to the WordPress dashboard page.

I downloaded a fresh WordPress copy, set up my database and ran `index.php` in the WordPress root folder. That does take me through the database questionary and up to the WordPress login page, and then the browser hangs there. It tries to load something and nothing happens. If I halt the browser and refresh, I'll get the 502 error and I'll keep getting this error on ANY OTHER files that I try to run from now on (it feels like something server-related breaks from within the IDE and I have to restart it).

The PHP 7 interpreter seems to be working fine, because I don't have an issue running any other of my ***non-WordPress*** projects.

The project address is `http://localhost:63342/wordpress/`, but I noticed this below link is shown in the PHP-CGI server window:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php-cgi -e -b 127.0.0.1:56502
```

Does this PHP CGI pointing to a different port number mean anything? I am new to WordPress and it was a breeze starting one in Cloud9, but I just don't understand why it doesn't work in PhpStorm 10.

As I said, there is the same problem on two machines (Windows, Mac, MAMP, XAMMP, and PhpStorm), so I know it is me who's missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Varying Vagrant Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) WordPress (VVV).

It's a better solution and will help you achieve better results without too much hassle.

I would recommend you to use a simple editor like [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) or [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) and install packages. I have personally lost many hours trying to get PhpStorm, MAMP, LAMP, and XAMPP work the way they should.

Comment: thanks Steve, so you think it is the Phpstorm IDE causing this issue? if i restart the IDE i can visit the startup WP page ONCE ( i.e. http://localhost:63342/wordpress ) but it crashes when i type http://localhost:63342/wordpress/wp-admin or click on the Dashboard link.  then nothing else works after that and everything breaks. same as you i have lost a lot of time trying to set up a simple WP project in  my Jetbrains editor and i just don't understand why i can't solve it

Comment: I'm a big fan of simplicity, I haven't seen any good documentation on how to correctly configure JetBrains. In my opinion, If I were starting again, I would go for a light editor and then migrate to a IDE, that can be configurable, but now IDEs lack much configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. It was the port number causing it to crash. My MAMP port number is 8888 (XAMPP is 80) and when I set up PhpStorm a year ago on both machines somehow I entered 63342 as server port number!

This never created any problem for me whatsoever running dozens of PHP projects since then, but obviously, it mattered to WordPress (dashboard). I went to PhpStorm settings and corrected the port number so it matches MAMP/XAMPP and all is working fine now.

It was a pretty basic (and silly) mistake to make on my part, but that wasted two full days in which I could have been teaching myself WordPress and developing themes/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it worked for me after configuring the built-in server port to 80 (I have used XAMPP)

Setting steps in phpstrom: [Configure the built-in web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html#configuring-built-in-web-server)

Comment: You are saying thanks for the insight the other answers provide, but not answering yourself, are you?